# Amazon machine image in AWS for Anaconda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, anaconda

Are there any amazon machine image available for Anaconda python in Amazon web services? I am looking for something that is similar to R AMI like this -->http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that you can use Predictive Analytics Framework AMI, unfortunately it isn't free (but you can get free trial).

You can get probably best results with your own AMI. The easiest way is to use one of free AMI, install all necessary packages, then create image from it.

Hope that this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to Devops. Do you have any tutorial or link which can i follow to create my own  AMI please?

Comment: Yeah. Because you are new to AWS so I was looking for the simplest material and I found is this video on YT. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2j3S2CfTQU . I hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there may not have been one when you first asked, but hopefully this answer will help others. There are several free Anaconda AMI options, for both Python 2 and 3. See https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=29f81979-a535-4f44-9e9f-6800807ad996&ref=dtl_B07CNFWMPC